# Ubuntu 12.10 does not see my ipod nano 8GB 4 Gen

Tags: 12.10, ipod

When I plug my Ipod into my computer it does not display it in my home folder or on the sidebar, But 12.04 does. Why?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! What doesn't display it? Windows? Ubuntu? You might want to add more information so people can help you out more easily.

Comment: After you connected your iPod open a terminal and enter `dmesg`? Please the last 5--10 lines of output to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu doesn't came with Apple devices support by default. To see your iPod, you must have `ifuse` installed. To install it, run:

```
sudo apt-get install ifuse
```

After that, replug your iPod, it should appear in nautilus